# I can define the listening port in asp.net Web Api c#

Tags: port, asp.net-web-api

As I can define the listening port in asp.net Web Api, especially GET
In the local application the url by default, when compiling the application is:

```
http: // localhost: 8181 /
```

When I publish it to the server, place it in the appropriate directory and the URL is:

> http://xxxyyyzzz-001-site1.mywindowshosting.com

If I sent GET requests to that URL and running, but I need you can define the port, eg 8181 as in the localhost.

> http://xxxyyyzzz-001-site1.mywindowshosting.com:8181

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Configuring ports to access the built web api is a server-side configuration problem. 
See your used server documentation on how to configure ports for your application.